# Need another ethernet port to use Wi-Fi extension. Use a splitter or a switch?

Tags: wireless-networking, internet, switch, splitter, wireless-extender

I need to connect a Wi-Fi extender to have Wi-Fi in my basement. I have one ethernet port which is connected to my TV. I wanted to know, if should I connect a splitter to also connect the extender or a switch. Of course I don't want to harm the internet speed which is 100mbps..
Ill be glad to know the differences between each one and why should and shouldn't use them.
Thank you

Comment: What do you mean by a "splitter"?

Comment: Search in Google ethernet splitter. It takes one port and makes it  into two from the other side

Comment: No, it does no such thing. There are actually several devices that are sometimes erroneously referred to as ethernet "splitters" and *none* of them turn one port into two. If you link to the actual device you're talking about, I can tell you what it does in fact do. But it definitely doesn't turn one Ethernet port into two.

Comment: For example, [this thing](https://www.walmart.com/ip/RJ45-1-to-2-Port-Female-to-Female-Network-Ethernet-Socket-LAN-Splitter-Adapter/704926397) that claims to be a "LAN splitter" (the first thing I found punching "ethernet splitter" into Google as you asked me to do) says that it "allows two computers to share one Ethernet line ONE AT A TIME, but it does not support both computer to connect onto the internet simultaneously". That is not splitting. So that is an example of a device erroneously referred to as a "splitter".

Comment: OK good to know. First off all, thanks for the explanation. Second, do you recommend buying a small switch for the issue I have?

Comment: It's hard to say because of a similar problem with "Wi-Fi extender". There are many devices that do different things that are referred to as an "extender" and I can't tell what kind of device you're asking about. But most likely, yes, a cheap 5-port gigabit switch would be your best choice. (You really don't want any special extender, you just want another access point, which can also be a WiFi router configured as an access point.)

Comment: I have an  edimax extender ew-438ac. It has an ethernet port to receive wire data and spread it as wireless. I thinking about buying a cheap switch so I'll be able to connect a cable into the device

Comment: That has an access point mode. Configure it as an access point with the same SSID and keys as your existing wifi router but on different channels.

Answer (score 0):

There are no Ethernet splitters that allow you to connect two devices to a single Ethernet port. What you want is a switch. Any cheap 5-port gigabit switch should work. They're practically free these days.

You don't really want a WiFi extender, you just want another access point. Most devices called "extenders" have an access point mode. You can configure the SSID and keys the same as your existing wireless network. Generally it's best to choose different channels.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! I already have an extender. I used it before as an extender but I wanted to use it as an access point just like you said! Thanks again